# Hosting a Windows server 2016 on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Static Public IP RDP Windows server I want to host through GCP,so as to get the  Security Feature to secure my server from RDP Attack and other...

What to Do ?

Comment: I think you "question" is too general. Can you please elaborate? What are you trying to do? Etc

Comment: I am already running a windows server By having a Static public IP , now Is there any way that I redirect GCP Server to My Windows Server .

Basically I want to Prevent MY server From Malware Attacks By using GCP

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is very broad I can only suggest to improve your servers's security:

Go to your [firewall settings in GCP](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list) console and set check/set up some rules:

- limit the number of IP's able to connect via RDP (leave just the ones you need)
- make sure ICMP response is turned off
- block all TCP/UDP ports and leave only the ones you use (like RDP)

You can check what rules are already in place when you create your VPC (in automatic mode you get some [prepoulated rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#more_rules_default_vpc) that allow to ping or rdp to an instances).

Lastly - - install all the latest updates on the server - it will also improve the security of your VM/

You can read more for example here - [how to harden your 2016 machine](https://www.tevora.com/10-essential-baseline-security-hardening-considerations-windows-server-2016/).

These are just simple rules to make your machine much more secure. If you want more detailed solution then update your question and put some more details about your use case.